# Syslog get spammed with "be2net" messages and probably prevent the server from rebooting

Tags: boot, server, cron, reboot

I've a crontab task which reboots my server every hour. This works in general pretty well just not after some time. As I wanted to know what the reason for that could be, I've looked into the syslog file and found something interesting. Always, before the server didn't started again from the shutdown/reboot, there were tons of messages containing "be2net". These messages came only when the server didn't started automatically again so I think that could be the reason.

My crontab tasks do look like this:

```
0 * * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now
@reboot /Client/start.sh
@reboot /Client2/start.sh
```

That are the messages which get sent before (there are **much** more, it's just to show that the server doesn't restart after it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkAXs.jpg

Does anyone have a idea how I can solve this issue/problem or maybe any other ideas what the reason for failed reboots/restarts could be?

Comment: *be2net* is a NIC driver. I don't see any warnings or errors associated with be2net and I suspect that the reason for the failure to reboot lies elsewhere. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 It's just pretty weird that these messages come only when the restart/reboot fails. They aren't there, when the reboot is/was successfull.

Comment: Rebooting your server every hour? That's nuts! What's the REAL reason behind that? It looks like you've got a read-only file system, which might indicate a disk problem. Is this a virtual machine, or real hardware? Please describe your system, and its disk configuration. Can you `fsck` your disk(s)?

Comment: It's a VPS server. `fsck` isn't working. The server is restarting every hour to prevent problems with the executed task. The tasks aren't the problem, tested it already a few days without (fresh reinstall) and the issues were still there. And, eventhough I would reboot the server every 10mins, that shouldn't be the reason or? Or can often reboots causes issues? Pretty new..